# My activity get closed without entering OnSaveInstanceState handle

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm closing my 2nd activity by clicking on a button, then triggering a "finish()" method. This shall do the same as pressing the back button on my device, and it does.
The problem is that it doesn't enter OnSaveInstanceState, which shall happen when destroying an activity. The result is that after re-entring this activity again, savedInstanceState == null, thus I cannot save my last variables' state.

```
    Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClose); 
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

From official documentation of the `onSaveInstaceState` :

> Do not confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as
>   onPause(), which is always called when an activity is being placed in
>   the background or on its way to destruction, or onStop() which is
>   called before destruction. **One example of when onPause() and onStop()
>   is called and not this method is when a user navigates back from
>   activity B to activity A**: there is no need to call
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) on B because that particular instance will
>   never be restored, so the system avoids calling it. **An example when
>   onPause() is called and not onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is when
>   activity B is launched in front of activity A**: the system may avoid
>   calling onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) on activity A if it isn't killed
>   during the lifetime of B since the state of the user interface of A
>   will stay intact.

You have two examples of when the `onSaveInstanceState` is not called. The most important part is the beginning :

> Do not confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as onPause(), which is always called when an activity is being placed in the background or on its way to destruction.

You **should not** expects that `onSaveInstanceState` will be called each time. This method is here to allow the Activity to save its *UI elements*. If you are trying to persists a variable value or something else (i.e. a value contained inside a View but which should be for the life time of the application - a username for example), you should use another mechanism like `SharedPreferences`.

**Sources**

[Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Comment: do not forget to accept this answer if it's ok for you ;)